# How can I receive custom email notifications when a resource is deleted in my AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, alert

Trying to set up alerting for deleted AWS resources and i tried to follow the guide outlined here

https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/config-email-resource-deleted

Although no errors are thrown during the setup process, i am not getting any alerts for dleted resources.

I am particularly looking for the most efficient way to get alerts on deletes of VPC, Route tables, subnets, TGW and other networking Services

i created an sns topic and subscribed to it

created an amazon event bridge rule with target as the SNS topic.

i have a feeling the issue may be with the SNS Access Policy but not sure what exactly i need to do

Comment: Hi, welcome. We need to see your event pattern at the very least please.

Comment: thanks, i have been able to resolve the issue myself